# Django Rest UpdateView: This field is required

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I have the following view:

```
class CampaignUpdate(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Campaign.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CampaignSerializer
    permission_classes = [CampaignDetailPermission]
    lookup_field = 'cid'
```

And I have the following test function:

```
    def test_update_campaign(self):
        request = self.factory.put(f'/', {'name': 'Updated Campaign'})
        force_authenticate(request, user=self.merchant)

        response = CampaignUpdate.as_view()(request, cid=self.campaign.cid)
        # Check that the response status code is 200 (OK)
        print(response.data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        # Check that the campaign was updated in the database
        self.assertEqual(Campaign.objects.get(cid=self.campaign.cid).name, 'Updated Campaign')
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
System check identified 4 issues (0 silenced).
..........{'shop': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]}
```

`shop` field is required for creation but i do not want to update this field everytime I update some other field.

How can I make it optional for update or readonly after creation?

In case, you need to see serializer:

```
class CampaignSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Campaign
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the serizlier:

```
class CampaignSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Campaign
        # fields = ['cid', 'name', 'shop', 'end_date', 'start_date', 'active']
        # read_only_fields = ['cid']
        fields = '__all__'

    def update(self, instance: Campaign, validated_data):
        instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
        instance.end_date = validated_data.get('end_date', instance.end_date)
        instance.start_date = validated_data.get('start_date', instance.start_date)
        instance.active = validated_data.get('active', instance.active)
        instance.shop = instance.shop
        print(instance)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Comment: This is the answer. Before partial update was not allowed. So, I override update method